# RecyclerView always scrolling to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My RecycleView has stable 7 items(weekdays) and each item contains one recycleView.

When I press any button specified for a concrete position the RecycleView scrolls to the bottom.

Activity:

```
private LinkedList<SupervisorTask> tasks;
private RecyclerView tasks_list;
private SnappingLinearSmoothScrolling manager;

private void setViewListeners() {
    ImageButton btn_mon = findViewById(R.id.btn_mon);
    ImageButton btn_tue = findViewById(R.id.btn_tue);
    ImageButton btn_wed = findViewById(R.id.btn_wed);
    ImageButton btn_thu = findViewById(R.id.btn_thu);
    ImageButton btn_fri = findViewById(R.id.btn_fri);
    ImageButton btn_sat = findViewById(R.id.btn_sat);
    ImageButton btn_sun = findViewById(R.id.btn_sun);

    View.OnClickListener scrollToDayListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_mon:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 0);
                case R.id.btn_tue:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 1);
                case R.id.btn_wed:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 2);
                case R.id.btn_thu:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 3);
                case R.id.btn_fri:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 4);
                case R.id.btn_sat:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 5);
                case R.id.btn_sun:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 6);
            }
        }
    };
    btn_mon.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
    btn_tue.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
    btn_wed.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
    btn_thu.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
    btn_fri.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
    btn_sat.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
    btn_sun.setOnClickListener(scrollToDayListener);
}

private void setViewAdapters() {
    tasks_list = findViewById(R.id.calendar_tasks_list);
    manager = new SnappingLinearSmoothScrolling(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    tasks_list.setLayoutManager(manager);
    tasks_list.setAdapter(new SupervisorTasksCalendarAdapter(tasks));
}
```

SnappingLinearSmoothScrolling.class:

```
public class SnappingLinearSmoothScrolling extends LinearLayoutManager {

public SnappingLinearSmoothScrolling(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
                                   int position) {
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new TopSnappedSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext());
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}

private class TopSnappedSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {
    TopSnappedSmoothScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
        return SnappingLinearSmoothScrolling.this
                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
        return SNAP_TO_START;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was unused break statements in switch-case block.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add  `break;` in your `switch` statement, Add it like below,

```
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_mon:
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 0);
            case R.id.btn_tue: 
                 break;
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 1);
            case R.id.btn_wed:
                 break;
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 2);
            case R.id.btn_thu:
                 break;
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 3);
            case R.id.btn_fri:
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 4);
            case R.id.btn_sat:
                 break;
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 5);
            case R.id.btn_sun:
                 break;
                tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 6);
                 break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just try replacing this in your code**

```
 View.OnClickListener scrollToDayListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_mon:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 0);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_tue:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 1);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_wed:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 2);
                break;
                case R.id.btn_thu:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 3);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_fri:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 4);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_sat:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 5);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_sun:
                    tasks_list.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(tasks_list, null, 6);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```